# Update the value in local storage and display it on web page without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular-local-storage

> I'm Currently working on Angular 8 project. I've a variable
> 'cartproductitems', what I want it to do update this variable as soon
> as user adds new product onto the cart. So that its number of items in
> the cart got updated. Everything is working fine except everytime I've
> to refresh my page whenever user adds new product into cart.

**My HTML Code**

```
   <div class="fw-700 mainNavCol" *ngIf="brand_Name!='Pipasha Restaurant'">
        <div class="fa-4x" style="position: relative !important;">
            <button class="btn-cart" (click)="callCheckout()"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              <span class="hidden-phone">My Trolley</span>
            </button>
            <span class="fa-layers-counter" style="background:Tomato; font-size: xx-large;">{{(""+cartProductItems)?.length}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**My TS Code**

```
cartProductItems: number;
this.cartProductItems = this._requestService.getProductCartItems();
    console.log('cartProductItems -> '+this.cartProductItems);
  callCheckout() {
    let isTable: boolean = JSON.parse(this._local.get('isTable'));
    if(isTable){
      this._requestService.tableCheckout(this.cartProductItems);
    }
    else{
      this._requestService.checkout(this.cartProductItems);
    }
    console.log('callCheckout -> isTable -> '+isTable);
  }
```

Comment: Please update the question with code where you are adding a product

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to give your button the button-Type? If none is defined, at least some browsers use them as submit, which might cause a request to the server.